# Calling Server.Execute on .NET .aspx page from classic ASP page

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Is it possible to call Server.Execute with a .NET .aspx page from classic ASP?  My tests so far have indicated this is not working but I'm still somewhat convinced there is a way.

Comment: No, it isn't possible.  (I'm pretty sure)

Comment: What are you trying to do, and would a redirect not maybe do the trick?

Comment: I am trying to embed a .aspx page inside an .asp page.  Ideally having all the html output as one page once it reaches the browser.  Previously I have been using an iframe embedded inside .asp page.  Works great but the .aspx page doesn't have access to Javascript, form data, etc. in the .asp page or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why on earth would you want that?

More or less guessing what you want to do: If you need to transparently display output from an .aspx in your .asp, you can always do this:

- use ServerXMLHTTP to execute the .aspx page
- read headers and content from http response
- write headers and content back out

Comment: I am going into look into some of those.  I had no idea about any of those possibilities.